# MailChimp Api v1.3 how to set subscriber to pending

Tags: php, api, email, mailchimp, deprecated

anyone out there still knows if its possible to set the new subscriber status to pending with Mailchimp Api **v1.3**?  the documentation is disabled/deprecated.

the payload for a new subscriber actually is:

```
$payload = array('email_address' => $this->email,
                'merge_vars' => $this->merge, 
                'email_type' => $this->emailType,
                'double_optin' => $this->doubleOptin,
                'update_existing' => $this->updateExisting,
                'replace_interests' => $this->replaceInterests,
                'send_welcome' => $this->sendWelcome,);
```

i tried to just add

```
"status" => "pending"
```

like with the Api v3, but this did not work.
i would like to check the docs if the naming was different back then but yeah...

thanks for reading by, help is much appreciated, have a nice one

Comment: Upgrading to API3.0 is not an option?

Comment: at least not right now, it would be the best solution but badly it has to happen later on in a different task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these is no solution to this. the only way was to actually upgrade to a package supporting MailChimp Api v3 (or doing the implementation yourself)

have a nice one.